# Java - Program will not Compile/method getText(double)

Tags: java, swing, methods, double, gettext

My program is suppose to make a GUI that calculates the square root of a number that is entered. I can not figure out why this code will not compile. I keep getting the following error message:

cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getText(double)

What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; //Next group of lines import various Java classes
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.text.*;

public class SquareRoot extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creates Window
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(450, 300);
        frame.setTitle("Find the Square Root");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel Numberlbl = new JLabel("Enter a number:");
        final JTextField NumberField = new JTextField(10);
        NumberField.setText("");

        JLabel Answerlbl = new JLabel("Square Root of your number is:");
        final JTextField AnswerField = new JTextField(10);
        AnswerField.setText("");

        JLabel ButtonLabel = new JLabel("Calculate Square Root");
        JButton button = new JButton("√");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
        panel.add(Numberlbl);
        panel.add(NumberField);
        panel.add(ButtonLabel);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(Answerlbl);
        panel.add(AnswerField);
        frame.add(panel);

        class CalculateListener implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                double NumberX = Double.parseDouble(NumberField.getText());
                double Answer = Math.sqrt(NumberX);
                AnswerField.setText(Answer);

            }
        }

        ActionListener listener = new CalculateListener();
        button.addActionListener(listener);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    }
```

Comment: If IDE doesn't say anithing about wrongs, but you get error "cann't find symbol" may be you have more then 1 JDK versions on computer. One JDK has NumberField.java. Secons JDK hasn't NumberField.java

Comment: Refresh your project. There is no method in your class with that syntax. I think your IDE referring to something not clean.

Comment: It would really help if you could name your variables in `camelCase` following normal conventions... also, say *where* you're getting the error message. I can't see any call to `getText(double)`...

Comment: Your code is VERY hard to read because you have violated a fundamental convention of Java: Class names start with uppercase, but methods and variable names start with lowercase characters.

Comment: @Jim - "VERY hard to read"? No, seriously... lowercase / uppercase makes zero difference whatsoever. Cramming too much on one line and writing yards of code without breaking it up - that makes code hard to read. Considering they're an apparent newbie, the OP actually did rather well with their code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only compilation error I got was for the AnswerField.setText() line - if you look at the API reference for setText() it takes a string, but you are trying to pass it a double.

Have a look at the NumberFormat class for converting the double to a string correctly. A simpler option is to use a Double object (as opposed to the double data type, note capitalization), and use its toString() method. A down-and-dirty method is to write it as ("" + Answer), since it will auto-convert it for you.

Comment: What is dirty with this approach?

Comment: Only the fact that it relies on implicit rather than explicit conversion and may not always work as intended. For example, in mainland Europe where the comma is the decimal separator, does it correctly show 3.14 as 3,14? I'm not entirely sure toString() would even get that right.

Comment: `d=3.14; "" + d` prints 3.14, and so does `"" + d.toString ()`, and `String.valueOf (d)` - one as dirty as the other.

Answer (score 1):

The code will not compile because the method setText(String text) expects a String parameter, and you are giving it a double.

To make your code work, use:

```
AnswerField.setText(String.valueOf(Answer));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final Double answer = Math.sqrt(NumberX);
AnswerField.setText(answer.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This one compiles. Here you go:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SquareRoot extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creates Window
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(450, 300);
        frame.setTitle("Find the Square Root");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel numberlbl = new JLabel("Enter a number:");
        final JTextField numberField = new JTextField(10);
        numberField.setText("");

        JLabel answerlbl = new JLabel("Square Root of your number is:");
        final JTextField answerField = new JTextField(10);
        answerField.setText("");

        JLabel buttonLabel = new JLabel("Calculate Square Root");
        JButton button = new JButton("√");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
        panel.add(numberlbl);
        panel.add(numberField);
        panel.add(buttonLabel);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(answerlbl);
        panel.add(answerField);
        frame.add(panel);

        class CalculateListener implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                double numberX = Double.parseDouble(numberField.getText());
                double answer = Math.sqrt(numberX);
                answerField.setText(""+answer);

            }
        }

        ActionListener listener = new CalculateListener();
        button.addActionListener(listener);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    }
```